# In DDD adding to the ubiquitous language?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I defined quickly my domain model in UML (on paper) and as I start to test drive out functionality, refactoring has led me to small classes that do no represent concepts in my domain but these classes nicely encapsulate the responsibility needed.

For example, I started with a Machine which has a number of licenses (Machine --->* License). I started with methods Add(licenseType) and remove(licenseType) which increased or decreased the corresponding license object in the list (i.e. license has a licenseType and a counter of the number of licenses of that type).

Machine has other associations and behaviors so I created a LicenseTypeManager where I now have Machine --->1 LicenseTypeManager --->* License.

I have Machine as an aggregate root, LicenseTypeManager as a Value object and License as a Value object.

Now LicenseTypeManager is something I created whilst refactoring and was not mentioned at all and is not part of the ubiquitous language of the application. Is it okay for it to exist?

In other words is it fine to model using UL and then find other terminology that may help in explaining the domain more clearly?

Also, I started to think that LicenseTypeManager could be a domain service but then I started to worry that I may be creating an anemic model (although there is still a lot of logic in the model). So my next question is should it be a domain service or should it remain where it is?

JD

Comment: 2 closes so far. Please advise why and how I can avoid it being closed?

Comment: Currently it has 2 close votes: 1st on "off topic", 2nd on "non constructive". Also - DDD is in "gray area". It is heavily abstract and stands between real world problem and software engineering. For one who is not familiar with DDD ideas - question might sound like a nonsensical gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter what causes enrichment of ubiquitous language. But it matters that it is ubiquitous.

So - if you model your domain and figure out new terms that eases understanding, there's nothing wrong with that as long as domain experts understands them, already uses or starts using them too.

Imagine you are selling cars and know nothing about programming.
Would `Car type manager` make any sense to you? Unlikely. It should not live in domain either.

As I see it:
 - you don't understand distinction between aggregate roots, entities and value objects
 - you lack knowledge of [OOP in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484593/what-might-be-a-good-object-oriented-programming-book-that-can-give-a-good-soli/5484769#5484769) (hence you seek for redemption through introduction of "managers")